# Button batteries vs 9V headache

Tags: arduino, batteries

I am working on an Arduino controller project with a few attached components returning data e.g. GPS and mini camera.

All works fine with USB power or 9V battery.

I tried using button cells in parallel creating approx. 9V (to save space) but the resulting battery does not seem to be able to power the components.

Is it a maximum current problem?

The button batteries are in three pairs connected in parallel.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much current does your project need? What is the part number of button cells? How is the connection? Can you draw?

Comment: Voltage doesn't add in parallel.  To get 9V, you have to stack a bunch of button cells in series.

Comment: Button cells are either 1.5V or 3V. If your "three pairs" means you have 2 cells in series then only 3V cells will give you enough voltage to be comparable to USB power. Having said that, I don't see how 6 button cells are much smaller than 9V battery, considering the size of the rest of your components

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb the V/ mAh impedance in an hour will depend on the energy density of the chemistry.  So size and weight matters for the effective series resistance and button cells are in the range of 1k which add in series while alkaline cells might be 1 Ohm +/-  an order of magnitude depending on size and quality.

So you have undersized your power requirements with excessive ESR, which the inverse defines your load regulation on open cell voltage.

You may be better off defining your mA max and mAh min requirements and look at LiPo flat packs.

Comment: Thankyou guys. Amazing answers. The cells are in serial pairs giving approx 6V. The three pairs are in parallel. Good point - they are approx the same volume but can be separated into smaller available spaces. Onwards to LiPo flatpacks... Thanks again for all the comments and questions :-)

Comment: yes but not same energy density as LiPo or mWh/gm

Comment: but do complete the answer with ticks